# How to show that the ratio of two linear second-order ODEs that solve $y'' + P(x)y' + Q(x)y = 0$ with a common zero at a point $x$ is constant.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So far I've figured out $$y_1''(x_0) + p(x_0)y_1'(x_0) = y_2''(x_0) + p(x_0)y_2'(x_0) = 0,$$ and I've thought about integrating or doing something with this to help show that $y_2/y_1$ is constant, but don't think I can since we only know the equation holds at the point $x_0$. You can get $$\frac{y_1}{y_2} = \frac{y_1''+P(x)y_1}{y_2'' + P(x)y_2}$$ just from plugging in the values, but I don't see how we can use these equations to show it's a constant.

If anyone could help me out I would appreciate it - thank you!

PS the problem is from Simmons' "Differential equations with Application and Historical Notes" (Section 14 exercise 10 - page 113)

Edit: I've thought about this a little more, and I think it might have something to do with the fact that a second ODE is uniquely determined by its equation, $y(x_0)$, and $y'(x_0)$. Since the equation and $y(x_0)$ are already picked the difference in the two solutions correlates between the difference in $y'(x_0)$, but I'm still not quite sure how this can help prove the ratio is constant.

Comment: Are we to assume that $x_0$ is not a singular point of the equation?

Comment: I'm pretty sure $x_0$ is just any point (where the solutions exist). The question in the book, word for word, is "If $y_1(x)$ and $y_2(x)$ are two solutions of equation (2) [the equation I wrote in the title] on an interval [a,b], and have a common zero in this interval, show that one is a constant multiple of the other (recall that a point $x_0$ is said to be a zero of a function f(x) if f(x) = 0)."

Comment: Will it help to show the Wronskian of the two solutions vanishes at that point?  In other words: Was there a discussion of how the Wronskian works just before this?  (Either the Wronskian is identically zero or never zero.)

Comment: Wronskian is discussed in the section right after this so I don't think that's the intended route, but if it works it works. Maybe something along the lines of the fact that the wronskian of the differential equation specified is either always 0 or never 0, and since it is 0 at $x_0$, it must always be 0, so the two functions must be linearly dependent?(although I don't think this shows that their ratio is constant/doesn't change)

Comment: Main things discussed in the section before this problem was a statement about existence and uniqueness for second order ODEs and a bit of an introduction in how we could solve some (maybe we can use the fact that any solution of the differential equation has the form $c_1y_1(x)+c_2y_2(x)$ and so $\frac{Y_1(x)}{Y_2(x)} = \frac{c_1y_1(x)+c_2y_2(x)}{d_1y_1(x)+d_2y_2(x)}$, and prove the last fraction is a constant somehow (using the fact that $Y_1(x_0)=Y_2(x_0)=0$), but I haven't had much luck with that either so far

Answer (score 1):

Consider the initial value problem
$$y''+P(x)y'+Q(x)y=0,\,\, y(x_0)=0, \,\,y'(x_0)=0.$$
Let $x_0$ be the common zero of $y_1(x), \, y_2(x)$. Assume $y_1(x)$ and $y_2(x)$ are not identically zero. Then $y_1'(x_0)\neq 0$ and $y_2'(x_0)\neq 0.$ (why? remember existence and uniqueness theorem for initial value problem). Consider
$$ \theta(x)=y_2'(x_0)\cdot y_1(x) - y_1'(x_0) \cdot y_2(x). $$
Then $\theta(x_0)=0$ and $\, \theta'(x_0)=0$. Thus $\theta(x)$ is a solution of our initial value problem. By existence and uniqueness theorem for initial value problem, $\theta(x)=0.$